# mysql varchar column search taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query the records which are exact matched with the provided string for one varchar column.

I try the below points and still taking too long.
Total records are over 200K.

```
LIKE 'Account Manager/Sales'

= 'Account Manager/Sales'

MATCH column AGAINST ('Account Manager/Sales')

Binary column = 'Account Manager/Sales'
```

For the Match, It is around 5 mintues.

As I can't afford to wait 5 minutes, is there any better approach to this kind of situation?

Comment: add index... dude... 200k records it's rather small DB... It should finish in less than 1 second

Answer (score -1):

Create an index on the column you search

EDIT:
based on the downvote I'm assuming you doing full text searches. Am I right ?

Even in that it will help to create a FULLTEXT index:

Comment: first, I don't downvote. but I am trying to use FULLTEXT too. and have index. but seem like it takes to long to execute.

Comment: sorry for the false accusation. Have you tried (if possible) to execute an explain plan to better understand how the query is executed ?